# Download button with timer

Tags: wordpress, button, timer, download

I want to access the download link after 30 seconds when the user clicks on the download link.
How to make download button with timer in my wordpress site.

This is my website : https://nuvl.ir/?p=4733

Pleas help me , i need this . Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<p>Click the button below to start the download:</p>
<button id="downloadButton" onclick="startDownload()">Download</button>

<script>
  function startDownload() {
    document.getElementById("downloadButton").innerHTML = "Please wait...";
    setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.href = "YOUR_DOWNLOAD_LINK_HERE";
    }, 30000); // 30 seconds delay
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello
Thanks for answering, unfortunately didn't work.